# Запятая между глаголами

Tags: глаголы, пунктуация

Здравствуйте! Нужна ли запятая в предложении: "Я шел улыбаясь". Видела разные варианты. "Я шел, улыбаясь, а он отвлекал Темных" (Сергей Лукьяненко. Ночной дозор). И еще: "Я шел улыбаясь ― мне казалось, что нужно улыбаться даже незнакомым..." (В. А. Каверин. Освещенные окна). Так как же правильно? Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. При решении задачи  нужно идти от смысла к форме, а таких форм у нас две:

а) Деепричастия и нераспространенные деепричастные обороты не обособляются, если они являются обстоятельствами образа действия в основном сообщении, при этом они обозначают не добавочное действие, а признак основного действия, как наречие.
 б) ТЕ ЖЕ САМЫЕ ВЫРАЖЕНИЯ могут быть обособлены, если  они имеют значение действия в дополнительном сообщении.

1. Работать надо с конкретным предложением, а не с абстрактным выражением.

Вариант "Я шел улыбаясь" непонятно о чем сообщает.  Предложение "Я шел, улыбаясь, а он отвлекал Темных"  ― вариант конкретный. Если не будем обособлять деепричастие, то оно становится  центром сообщения , а при обособлении уходит на второй план. Получается: Я шел (улыбаясь), а он отвлекал. Видно, автор подразумевал именно этот смысл.

```
 В предложении  "Я шел улыбаясь ― мне казалось, что нужно улыбаться даже незнакомым" ситуация обратная. Здесь автор, наоборот, подчеркивает улыбку на лице героя, а обособление эту улыбку отодвинуло бы на второй план.
```

"Я шел почти весь путь улыбаясь". Предложение неудачно по структуре для обоих вариантов, его надо переделать. Обособленный вариант: Я шел домой, почти весь путь улыбаясь. Необособленный вариант: Почти весь путь я шел улыбаясь (с улыбкой). Переделка заключается в том, чтобы сделать структуру предложения уравновешенной: Почти весь путь (повышение тона, пауза) я шел улыбаясь (понижение тона).

Comment: София, спасибо Вам большое за такой развернутый ответ, но, честно говоря, боюсь я не все поняла. Увы, я не так сильна в русском языке. Что касается смысла, то если текст выглядит, например, так: "Мне вспомнилась история из моего детства. Это было очень приятное воспоминание. И я шел, почти весь путь улыбаясь". Тогда запятая нужна?

Comment: Запятая нужна: И я шел, почти весь путь улыбаясь.При выборе знак надо просто прочитать предложение с правильной интонацией. Это несложно - думаю, писатели грамматический анализ не проводят, а делают это чисто интуитивно. А при чтении текста надо знать, что предложение ЛЮБОЙ структуры состоит из отдельных речевых отрезков - фраз, разделенных паузами. Приемы интонационного анализа намного проще, чем грамматического, этому можно научить за час. Но никто учить и учиться не будет - наверное, еще время не настало.

Comment: Интонационный анализ, конечно, замечательно (без иронии), но без грамматического не обойтись. Не всегда паузе в  устной речи соответствует наличие пунктуационного знака.

Comment: Совершенно справедливо.  Каждое предложение имеет свою грамматику и свою интонацию, и это учитывается в комплексе. Вот, например, по данной теме. Сначала мы определяем возможные грамматические формы (обособленную и необособленную) и их значения, и только затем переходим к интонационно-структурному анализу. Интонация передает те тонкие оттенки смысла,которые оказываются РЕШАЮЩИМИ при выборе знака, а также определяет читаемость предложения. Писатели же интуитивно чувствуют правильность художественной формы, даже если не могут своё чувство объяснить.

Comment: И не только писатели...

Answer (score 2):

Здесь потиворечивая ситуация. Розенталь пишет, что одиночные деепричастия обособляются, когда обозначают не признак действия (как? каким образом?), а добавочное действие. Предпочтение для запятой в этом случае имеют деепричастия, стоящие перед глаголом-сказуемым. В Вашем предложении деепричастие стоит после глагола, но имеет значение добавочного действия, хотя и признак действия присутствует тоже (шел КАК? с улыбкой). И последний аргумент: здесь деепричастие очень тесно связано со сказуемым (важно не то, что я шел (все равно что БЫЛ), а то, что шел улыбаясь). В таком случае запятая не ставится.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Значит в данном случае запятая не нужна. А если бы предложение имело вид: "Я шел почти весь путь улыбаясь", то что-то изменилось бы? В плане постановки запятой.

Comment: > но имеет значение добавочного действия, хотя и признак действия присутствует тоже (шел КАК? с улыбкой). И последний аргумент: здесь деепричастие очень тесно связано со сказуемым (важно не то, что я шел (все равно что БЫЛ), а то, что шел улыбаясь).
Последний аргумент у Вас повторяет предпоследний. То есть реально декларируется факт *улыбчивой ходьбы*. Улыбка как признак действия наряду с хромотой?
С запятой, если уж дать право на жизнь такому карлику. Второе предложение — нормальное, тоже с запятой.

Comment: Ммарина. Ваш новый вариант предложения - это уже предложение с деепричастным оборотом, а обороты почти всегда обособляются. Прочитал здесь много комментариев, пока меня не было час на сайте, и хочу заметить, что приведенные аргументы интересны, но очень уж сложны умозаключения. По-моему, надо подходить к вопросу немного проще, практичнее, иначе влезем в такие дебри, что из них потом не выбраться.

Comment: Т.е. в данном случае запятая нужна? "И я шел, почти весь путь улыбаясь"

Comment: Да, конечно

Comment: Хоть я и не совсем разобралась в правилах постановки запятой, но большое Вам спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Вы можете кликнуть слева вверху на  поднятый палец